# Filter sql query results using static values from "Select list" page item in Oracle APEX 5.0

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I'm looking for a way to filter and display records using static values from a "Select list" page item. I have created a bar chart in APEX 5.0 using the following query:

```
  select to_char(to_date(time_stamp,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS') as label, col2 as value from table1 where :P5_NEW_1 = col1 ;
```

The time_stamp column of `table1` is of datatype `varchar2` in my database and contains the date values in the format `YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS`

e.g., values like below are stored in the `time_stamp` column

```
2015-08-26-10:17:15
2015-08-26-13:17:15
2015-09-17-12:45:54
2015-09-17-14:12:32
2015-10-06-10:01:42
2015-10-06-11:01:28
2015-10-06-05:01:28
```

and so on...

I have added a "Select list" item named "interval" on my form that contains a pre-populated list of values like `1hr`, `6hrs`.

Now I want to modify the above query such that following should happen:

- For the value of `1hr` selected from the drop down list, the query should check the `time_stamp` column and display the records for the last one hour

  (i.e., records which fall in range `to_char(sysdate - 1/24 ,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS')   to   to_char(sysdate ,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS'`)
- And for the value of `6hrs` selected from the drop-down list, the query should display records for the last 6 hours.

  (i.e., records which fall in range `to_char(sysdate - 6/24 ,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS'  to   to_char(sysdate ,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS'`) )

How do I modify my SQL query to add the above condition in my current SQL query, using static values from page item select list?

Comment: time_stamp can be (sysdate-1/24), and will depend on which interval is selected right?

Comment: I want to modify the sql query to cover above conditions. Based on the input selected from drop down list the query should display records with those particular date ranges.

Comment: can i ask whats the return of your static values?if 1hr is selected, whats the return value?and whats the value of P5_NEW_1?what is its significance to the query?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try this:

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(time_stamp,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS') AS label, col2 AS VALUE
FROM table1 
WHERE :P5_NEW_1 = col1 AND
to_date(time_stamp,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') BETWEEN
       (SYSDATE - (to_number(:SELECT_LIST_ID,'99')/24)) AND SYSDATE;
```

> Just make sure that the static values has a return value equal to **`hr`** itself

For example, if static value is equal to `1HR` then return value should be `1`

> `:SELECT_LIST_ID` is the select list id which holds the static values for the interval.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying to understand the syntax you have posted.

Please note the static list contains alphanumeric values -> 1hr,6hrs.

Hence I think to_number(:SELECT_LIST_ID,'99')/24))  will not work if I replace :SELECT_LIST_ID with 1hr and 6hrs

Please comment

Comment: You've said in your post that those values are contained in a select list, am i right?thus, select list requires list of values, it will be either static or dyanmic,since you said that those are static values, it should have return values.If you dont have any return values, how did you make your select list?

Comment: when working with select list,  whether its static or dynamic,always keep in mind that it requires two values, display value and the return value, display value is the value that the user can see when choosing option, while return value is the value that will be submitted.

Comment: If you are really using static values for a select list as what you have told, then your list of values should look like this. STATIC:1hr;1,6hrs;6,etc...

Comment: I tried using the changes you suggested, however, it seems the query is still not filtering the results when I pass the static values.Do I need to convert  the sysdate to format YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS for between clause since the time_stamp is of varchar2 datatype?

Comment: can you make an example of your page in apex.oracle.com?you dont have to convert sysdate since time_stamp which is varchar2 is converted to date in the query